# After invalid login, showing null reference exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication, authorization, asp.net-identity

This is my Controller code:

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (!await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id))
            {
                ViewBag.Email = user.Email;
                return View("UnconfirmedAccount");
            }
        }
 // Error is showing at this line System.nullReferenceException
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

I am login the user with email and password.If login id and password are correct then SignInStatus.Success case calls succesfully.
But,if login fails then its showing system.NullRefernceException.

**Now, most important thing, i have seperated username and email successfully at register times.Now, at registration i am saving email and username in their respective column.Before email also got saved in username column.
But after seperating username and email, i was unable to login so i have to change this line in login action method fro this:**

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

to this:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

I just want to show invalid login attempt message as it was showing before not this yellow screen. how to do it.

Comment: Can you show your LoginViewModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple,
After finding user from UserManager, you are checking if `user` is null

```
    var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
    if (user != null)
    {
        ....
    }
```

And again you are using user object outside that check

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

so `user` is null and it is throwing null reference exception when you trying to access user.UserName.

Comment: That check is for checking whether accnt is confirmed or not if not then code is again sent to his/her email id to restrict user to login without any email id.Now, in my case user is null so it should hit last case and show user the msg "Invalid login attempt."

Comment: `if(user != null)` will check if user object is null or not. In your case user is null then, you are trying to access `user.UserName` as shown in answer before your switch case, which is throwing exception.